# Display Distinct data from Join query

Tags: sql-server, join, distinct, case

Basically I have 2 tables. Lets say A and B.

A has columns like id(PK), pin, name, address

```
id(PK)  pin             name    address
1        aaa-111-aaa    AAA ------
2        bbb-222-bbb    BBB ------
3        ccc-333-ccc    CCC --------
```

B has columns like appName, apprequestTime, appAccectTime, id(FK).

```
appName apprequestTime  appAccectTime    id(FK).
LLL          2012-4-01  2012-4-01    1
NNN          2012-4-08  2012-5-01    2
QQQ          2012-4-05  2012-4-01    1
MMM          2012-4-02  2012-4-02    2
PPP          2012-5-01  2012-5-01    1
```

There can be multiple id rows in the B table as it is Foreign Key.

Now, the problem is I am trying to get all the records of one pin of a certain apprequestTime.

I am trying inner join but it shows  the pin because of the id in table B.

```
pin         apprequestTime
aaa-111-aaa     2012-4-01
aaa-111-aaa     2012-4-05
bbb-222-bbb     2012-4-08
bbb-222-bbb     2012-4-02
```

but the result I am expecting should be:

```
pin            apprequestTime
aaa-111-aaa    2012-4-01
               2012-4-05
bbb-222-bbb    2012-4-08
               2012-4-02
```

Can any one help:)

Comment: use some scripting language to format the first output to second

Comment: thanks but i need to use SQL query

Comment: @Aqua - What RDBMS and version are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Postresql?

Comment: @Ankur - If you're using SQL Server, I'm sure you could build a CTE using `ROWNUMBER` to do it, but I suck at CTE's.

Comment: Try to "group by" pin and get the results. All of the apprequestTime may not get printed in the results, but if you are using a language like Java, you will be able get those grouped results from result set. FYI, my knowledge is on MySQL and not other databases.

Comment: i tried groupBy with pin but then it asks for apprequestTime to be grouped with. Even when I use apprequestTime, same result comes in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use `row_number()` for this type of request:

```
;with cte as
(
  select a.pin, b.apprequestTime,
    row_number() over(partition by a.pin 
                      order by b.apprequestTime) rn
  from tablea a
  inner join tableb b
    on a.id = b.id
) 
select case when rn = 1 then pin else '' end pin, 
  apprequestTime
from cte;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22a98/8)

Or without CTE:

```
select case when rn = 1 then pin else '' end pin, 
  apprequestTime
from 
(
  select a.pin, b.apprequestTime,
    row_number() over(partition by a.pin 
                      order by b.apprequestTime) rn
  from tablea a
  inner join tableb b
    on a.id = b.id
) t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22a98/10)

Comment: Didn't know about `row_number() over`. Seems useful :-)

Comment: @Aqua happy to help. if any of the answers on here are helpful, be sure to upvote and/or accept them via the checkmark on the left.  It helps future visitors and it increases your repuation as well. :)

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much for both for the answer and the reminder:) Btw, can you please explain what exactly happening in without CTE example? And is it possible to do the same thing with LINQ?

Comment: @Aqua CTE is similar to a subquery but it have the ability to do other functions -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx for more info on CTE

Comment: @Aqua I am not familiar with LINQ

Comment: And what about the without CTE answer you gave? What is exactly going on inside the query? Can u please explain step step? Sorry, I am bothering you so much. But I kind of trying to learn:)

Comment: @Aqua the second query is a subquery that applies the `row_number()` to each record. The `row_number()` value is then used to decide whether or not you display the `pin`, the `case` statement is saying that you only display the `pin` value when the `row_number() = 1`.